# Using Spring and html forms to get an object

Tags: java, forms, spring

I am trying to learn Spring framework by building simple website, now I have a problem.

I would want to make something like this: user chooses which file to upload and chooses from a list what type of file it is. For now I have something like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="uploadItem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form_elem">
        <label for="file">File</label> 
        <input type="file" name="fileData"/>
</div>
<div class="form_elem">
        <label for="file_type">File type</label> 
        <form:select path="fileType">
                    <form:options items="${fileTypes}" />
        </form:select>
</div>
<input type="submit"/>
</fieldset>
```

now in my controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addWordFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFileAdder(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(new UploadItem());
    model.addAttribute("fileTypes", Arrays.asList("first type", "second type"));
    return "questionFileAdd";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addWordFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processUploadedFile(UploadItem uploadItem, Model model)
        throws Exception {
    String type=uploadItem.getFileType();
    return showFileAdder(model);
}
```

here is the problem, when user chooses type of the file, I get only a String and I would need to manually create an object, like SimpleFileFileReader using class for name or just using big switch-case statement for every type of file I support.

Is it possible to show String in html form, but when it is processed I would get an object of some class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather an OO question than a Spring question. What you want is a factory of SimpleFileReader. Simply using a `Map<String, SimpleFileReader>` could be your solution:

- the `keySet()` of the map contains all the file types
- once you get the file type from the GUI, use `map.get(fileType)` to get the SimpleFileReader associated to this type

You could also use en enum:

```
public enum FileType {
    TYPE_1 {
        public SimpleFileReader getFileReader() {
            return new Type1SimpleFileReader();
        }
    },

    TYPE_2 {
        public SimpleFileReader getFileReader() {
            return new Type2SimpleFileReader();
        }
    };

    public abstract SimpleFileReader getFileReader();
}
```

The `FileType.values()` gives you the array of file types. Spring can automatically map an input field to an enum, and getting the associated file reader is as simple as

```
SimpleFileReader reader = fileType.getFileReader();
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't figure out the simplest solution :)